# How to return all the minimum indices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am a little bit confused reading the documentation of [argmin function in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html).
It looks like it should do the job:

Reading this

> Return the indices of the minimum values along an axis.

I might assume that

```
np.argmin([5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1])
```

will return an array of all indices: which will be `[3, 4, 5, 7]`

But instead of this it returns only `3`. Where is the catch, or what should I do to get my result?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

That documentation makes more sense when you think about multidimensional arrays.

```
>>> x = numpy.array([[0, 1],
...                  [3, 2]])
>>> x.argmin(axis=0)
array([0, 0])
>>> x.argmin(axis=1)
array([0, 1])
```

With an axis specified, `argmin` takes one-dimensional subarrays along the given axis and returns the first index of each subarray's minimum value. It doesn't return all indices of a single minimum value.

To get all indices of the minimum value, you could do

```
numpy.where(x == x.min())
```

Answer (score 25):

See the documentation for [`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) (which is referred to by the docs for `numpy.argmin`):

> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

The phrasing of the documentation ("indices" instead of "index") refers to the multidimensional case when `axis` is provided.

So, you can't do it with `np.argmin`. Instead, this will work:

```
np.where(arr == arr.min())
```

Answer (score 5):

I would like to quickly add that as user grofte mentioned, `np.where` returns a tuple and it states that it is a shorthand for `nonzero` which has a corresponding method `flatnonzero` which returns an array directly.

So, the cleanest version seems to be

```
my_list = np.array([5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1])
np.flatnonzero(my_list == my_list.min())
=> array([3, 4, 5, 7])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the indices of a list, not a numpy array, try

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = [5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1]
np.where(np.array(my_list) == min(my_list))[0]
```

The index [0] is because numpy returns a tuple of your answer and nothing (answer as a numpy array). Don't ask me why.

Comment: This doesn't work as is. Equality doesn't broadcast with python lists.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended way (by numpy documents) to get all indices of the minimum value is:

```
x = np.array([5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1])
a, = np.nonzero(x == x.min())  # a=>array([3, 4, 5, 7])
```