# How to use out parameter in numpy.argmin to retrieve minimum indices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

According to [numpy.argmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin) documentation, the third parameter **out** should provide indices (as I understand):

> **out** : *array, optional*
>   If provided, the result will be inserted into
>   this array. It should be of the appropriate shape and type.

But I am having trouble using it to collect indices of minimum twenty of a large numpy.ndarray (*dist* in following snippet).

```
# here using smaller size arrays, but hold RGBs of images    
a = np.random.normal(size=(10,3))
b = np.random.normal(size=(1,3))
# compute distances between two arrays
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(a,b)
index_of_minimum = np.argmin(dist)
# create an array to hold the indices: same shape and same datatype
indices = np.array(dist.shape, dtype=np.float64)
np.argmin(dist, axis=0, out=indices)
```

But I get following error:

> ValueError: output array does not match result of np.argmin.

There was a similar questions asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18582178/7073762) but my requirement is somewhat different. First, is it possible to collect indices of minimum using *out* parameter? If so how can I do that?

Comment: You don't have to provide an`out` parameter.  `indices=argmin(dist, axis=0)` works just as well.

Comment: You should be using `np.zeros`, not `np.array` to create an intial 'empty' array.  Play with those in an interpreter to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more than one index. I was hoping if I use **out** all the indices like [4, 5, 6, ..] could be collected.

Comment: You mean there are multiple elements that have the same minimum value? And you want all of there indices? The `out` won't help.  Or do you want the smallest `n`values?  You need to give a concrete example, preferably in a new question.

Comment: **dist** has following values: `array([[ 1.80575419],
       [ 1.8899017 ],
       [ 2.01251239],
       [ 1.23996376],
       [ 1.71429128],
       [ 1.43630964],
       [ 1.75586222],
       [ 1.3196145 ],
       [ 0.92899127],
       [ 1.57403994]])` **np.argmin(dist)** provides only one index, in this case 8. What I want is `indices = [8, 2, 7, ..., 1]`.

Comment: Have you looked at `argpartition`?  Or `argsort`?

Comment: Gr8! `argsort` did the trick for me. `indices = np.argsort(dist, axis=0, kind='merge')` then slice to collect minimum few `indices[0::2]` But I wish someone provides an example explaining how to collect indices using `argmin`. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: First there is a type in your line 6. It should say

```
dist
```

rather than

```
list
```

This does not influence the last part though.

The second problem is the shape of indices. It works for me with

```
indices = np.zeros(dist[0].shape, dtype=np.int64)
```

For an index array you need integer type. Due to axis=0 the expected shape has one less dimension than the original dist array. You get this by explicitly taking out the 0-axis in the initiation of indices

Comment: Thanks, both of your suggestions are useful. But the _indices_ have only one index, just like **np.argmin** without optional params. I want _indices_ filled with all minimum, next min... largest.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you provide in a comment:

```
In [1856]: data
Out[1856]: 
array([[ 1.80575419],
       [ 1.8899017 ],
       [ 2.01251239],
       [ 1.23996376],
       [ 1.71429128],
       [ 1.43630964],
       [ 1.75586222],
       [ 1.3196145 ],
       [ 0.92899127],
       [ 1.57403994]])
In [1857]: i=np.argmin(data,axis=0)
In [1858]: i
Out[1858]: array([8], dtype=int32)
In [1859]: data[i]
Out[1859]: array([[ 0.92899127]])
```

`argmin` returns the index of one element - the one and only one minimum.

And for the 3 smallest values:

```
In [1878]: i=np.argsort(data,axis=0)[:3]
In [1879]: data[i.ravel()]
Out[1879]: 
array([[ 0.92899127],
       [ 1.23996376],
       [ 1.3196145 ]])
```

You already found an answer to finding `all` the minimum value indices.  But that answer is meaningful only in the case of integers.  Due to rounding only specially crafted floats are equal to each other.

[How to return all the minimum indices in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582178/how-to-return-all-the-minimum-indices-in-numpy)

I could though find all the values that close to the minimum.  Here it looks like .5 would be interesting:

```
In [1885]: i=np.argmin(data,axis=0)
In [1886]: i
Out[1886]: array([8], dtype=int32)
In [1887]: m=data[i[0]]
In [1888]: m
Out[1888]: array([ 0.92899127])
In [1889]: data==m    # only 1 value equals the minimum
Out[1889]: 
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

but ones close to it can be found with:

```
In [1890]: np.abs(data-m)<.5
Out[1890]: 
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
 In [1892]: data[(data-m)<.5]
 Out[1892]: array([ 1.23996376,  1.3196145 ,  0.92899127])
```

I don't need the `abs` since `m` is minimum.  `np.isclose(data,m,atol=.5)` also works.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. 

> I could though find all the values that close to the minimum.

Since the lists I am dealing with are somewhat large (`> 518400` and loops) I prefer a solution _faster_ than sorting (`argsort`). If there is a way to find **indices** rather than values (`data[(data-m)<.5]`), your solution suits me. (FYI I need index of minimums to find which pairs have minimum distances in `a` and `b` in the original post.)