# How to find the closest non null values to a target value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sorry for the title but basically I'm dealing with a dataset that looks like a pacman game.

So I need to find the coordinates of the closest ghosts to the pacman.

```
import pandas as pd

pacman = [
    list("          G"),
    list("  P  G     "), 
    list("    G      "),
    list("        G  "),
    list(" G         "),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(pacman)
print(df)

  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0                                G
1       P        G               
2             G                  
3                         G      
4    G
```

I expect (0, 10) and (1, 5) as an output since they are the coordinates of the closest ghosts to pacman

My code below gives only `(0, 10)`. Can you explain why please or give other solution ?

```
data = df.values.flatten()
g_indices = np.where(data == 'G')[0]
p_indices = np.where(data == 'P')[0]
min_index = np.argmin(np.abs(g_indices - p_indices))
g_index = g_indices[min_index]
coordinates = (df.iloc[:, g_index].idxmax(), g_index)
print(coordinates)
(0, 10)
```

Comment: [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy-argmin) will only return a single index even if there are multiple values that are equal to the minimum (see the "Notes" in the linked documentation). Instead see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582228/1862861 to get all the values that match the minimum.

Comment: What is your definition of "closest"? You have a 2D array but handle its flatten version, as if the world was actually a single line. Shouldn't you consider the euclidean distance? Is the world a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus)?

Comment: @MattPitkin, ok i will try to use that.

Comment: @mozway, i'm not famililar with this concept and what is the euclidean distance ? i'm just need to have the closest value to P (from both directions) in a 1D array.

Comment: Well, you should read [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) it's an important basic concept. I believe in terms of your pacman, the 2D distance makes more sense since the ghost can travel in any distance (you don't have defined paths here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2D

Assuming you want the closest(s) in terms of [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```
x, y = np.where(df.eq('P'))    # get pacman position
xg, yg = np.where(df.eq('G'))  # get ghosts positions

dist = (xg-x)**2 + (yg-y)**2   # compute square of distance
mask = dist == dist.min()      # get minimum distance

# format output
closest = list(zip(df.index[xg[mask]], df.columns[yg[mask]]))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 4)]
```

Other example:

```
# input
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0     G                          G
1     G  P  G     G               
2        G     G                  
3                          G      
4     G                           

# output
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2)]
```

### 1D

If you really want to consider your input as 1D, do the same in 1D and restore the original indices with [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
a = df.to_numpy().ravel()

x = np.where(a == 'P')[0]
xg = np.where(a == 'G')[0]

dist = abs(xg-x)
closest = list(zip(*np.unravel_index(xg[dist==dist.min()], df.shape)))

closest
# [(0, 10), (1, 5)]
```

Comment: Great and very advanced but thanks

Comment: It should be noted that the 2D solution actually uses Euclidean distance *squared*. To calculate the Euclidean distance, we would have to calculate the square root. Non-negative numbers compare like their squares so we can avoid a costly square root calculation.

Comment: @Friedrich In terms of minimum, the minimum of the distance or squared distance is the same. It's true that it's not the distance *per se* but for this particular application this saves a useless step ;)

Comment: I edited the comment for correctness

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded like a lecture. My point was that you wrote a good and efficient solution. OP seems not so versed in maths so I thought I'd better add a little bit of explanation.

Comment: @Friedrich don't worry, I'm happy that you commented. I actually hesitated to comment on that and thought that it wasn't too important. But it is :)